# Unix/Linux Do ever command have return value?

Tags: linux, unix, fedora, rhel

In Linux or Unix based systems, do every command have return value?

If yes then return value 0 = successful execution and >0 = not successful?

Can I imagine that every command is a like function which accepts some parameters and returns some values?

Comment: You should check the documentation for the commands you are interested in. The exit codes don't have the same meaning across differing programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, every program in every major OS returns a value to the caller. You can get at this value by using `echo $?` in Linux.

And you're correct that 0 generally means success and any other value generally indicates something went wrong.  But exact values are program specific and do not have to conform to this norm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because that is the case.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // returns an int.
}
```

Or, just do a

```
/bin/true
echo $?
0
/bin/false
echo $?
1
```